# ComboBox with localizable ComboBoxItems specified in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, markup-extensions

I have a ComboBox which I'd like to populate with members of an enum, with localized representative strings.  I know the standard way to do this is to make a Dictionary in codebehind with the enum values as keys and the text as values, and then set the ItemsSource to that.  But then I wouldn't be able to use my sexy MarkupExtension.  So, I'd like to do this in XAML.  I thought it would be easy; here's what I have:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbNewTabPos"
            DisplayMemberPath="Content"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=NewTabPosition}"
            SelectedValuePath="Tag">
            <ComboBoxItem
                Content="{qt:Resx Key=SomeKey, Index=0}" 
                Tag="{x:Static qt:TabPos.Left}"/>
            <ComboBoxItem
                Content="{qt:Resx Key=SomeKey, Index=1}"
                Tag="{x:Static qt:TabPos.Right}"/>
            <ComboBoxItem
                Content="{qt:Resx Key=SomeKey, Index=2}"
                Tag="{x:Static qt:TabPos.Leftmost}"/>
            <ComboBoxItem
                Content="{qt:Resx Key=SomeKey, Index=3}" 
                Tag="{x:Static qt:TabPos.Rightmost}"/>
        </ComboBox>
```

It almost works; the dropdown is populated correctly, the binding is working, I can see the selected value when I pull down the dropdown, but the box part of the combobox remains blank no matter what I do.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I write this little example and it works fine.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindowCommandBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources >
        <Point x:Key="1_2" X="1" Y="2"/>
        <Point x:Key="1_3" X="1" Y="3"/>
        <Point x:Key="1_4" X="1" Y="4"/>
        <Point x:Key="1_5" X="1" Y="5"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbNewTabPos"
        DisplayMemberPath="Y"
        SelectedValuePath="Tag"
        SelectedValue="1"
         Margin="0,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="135" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=1_2}" Tag="1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=1_3}" Tag="2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=1_4}" Tag="3"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=1_5}" Tag="4"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

I think you are not using `DisplayeMemberPath="Content"` properly. That is used to specify which value to display from the selected object. The selected object is not the selected ComboBoxItem but what is in the `Content` Property of the selected ComboBoxItem. But from your code I can see that object in your ComboBoxItems only have two properties named `"Key"` and `"Index"`. 
Hope this help. If I misunderstood, please let me know.

Comment: Turns out `DisplayeMemberPath="Content"` was exactly the problem.  Just removing that line from the code I posted makes it work perfectly.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!